# Poison the well - well is poisoned

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does it mean when someone says:

"You have to decide if the well is poisoned for you."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To poison a well means to render it permanently (or for a very long time) unusable.  So to use it an idiom in the example you give, it means "you must decide if the situation has been damaged or compromised beyond repair".